# multiple wordpress installs, getting data from wp-2 while inside wp-1

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site with 4 wordpress installs, (no need for wp-MU) x4 databases, with each a unique username and pass...

i will call these 
   wp1=mainsite
   wp2=childsite
   wp3=childsite
   wp4=childsite

In wp1, there is a page, with tabs, which should load recent posts from the wp2, wp3, wp4 installs, this page is using a custom template to provide the page with php code which should connect to each database and return the data for each...

code:

```
$db_wp2_user = 'db_user'
$db_wp2_pwd = 'db_pass';
$db_wp2_db = 'db_name';
$db_wp2_host = 'localhost';
$wpdb_wp2 = new wpdb($db_wp2_user, $db_wp2_pwd, $db_wp2_db, $db_wp2_host);

//query
$wp2_latestposts = $wpdb_wp2->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb_wp2->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ");

foreach ($wp2_latestposts as $latestpost) {
  echo $latestpost->post_title."<br />";
}


$db_wp3_user = 'db_user'
$db_wp3_pwd = 'db_pass';
$db_wp3_db = 'db_name';
$db_wp3_host = 'localhost';
$wpdb_wp3 = new wpdb($db_wp3_user, $db_wp3_pwd, $db_wp3_db, $db_wp3_host);

//query
$wp3_latestposts = $wpdb_wp3->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb_wp3->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ");

foreach ($wp3_latestposts as $latestpost) {
  echo $latestpost->post_title."<br />";
}

$db_wp4_user = 'db_user'
$db_wp4_pwd = 'db_pass';
$db_wp4_db = 'db_name';
$db_wp4_host = 'localhost';
$wpdb_wp4 = new wpdb($db_wp4_user, $db_wp4_pwd, $db_wp4_db, $db_wp4_host);


//query
$wp4_latestposts = $wpdb_wp4->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb_wp4->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post' ");

foreach ($wp4_latestposts as $latestpost) {
  echo $latestpost->post_title."<br />";
}
```

each call, to each database should display the latest posts from each database..
on that single page... loaded into each tab...

when the code is run the page comes back with all styles and the footer, 
but were the information should load its blank, with no error messages,

can you tell me if this is the proper way to perform this action, or if there is an easier way to populate an array if the data is stored in another database, outside your main wp install?

Answer (score 1):

During the install you can put in a prefix, so you can install as many WP installs as you want in the same database. This might be easier for what you're trying to do.

[Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs)

Comment: thanks jeremy this was one option when setting up the sites, but thought best to be different databases..

im sure there was a way to connect even when the main wordpress site is loaded... ive tried using the conventinal mysql connection string to get the info which works, but then i feel like im starting from scratch, which i would have to build out the joining queries to get all the relevant info, were as wp has this already at hand, if i can get to use the class info.. if that makes sence.